# Where do files go when you delete them programatically with swift?

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

Where do files go when you delete them programatically? I deleted them with this code, but the Trash for today is empty. Is it possible to retrieve them?

```
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        do{
            let filelist = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(fontFolderPath)
            for filename in filelist {
                do{ try filemgr.removeItemAtPath(fontFolderPath+filename)} catch{}
            }
        }catch{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the URL related API of NSFileManager you have two options:

- `func removeItemAtURL(_ URL: NSURL) throws`

  deletes the item immediately like `/bin/rm` in Terminal.app and has the same functionality as `removeItemAtPath`.
- `func trashItemAtURL(_ url: NSURL,
  resultingItemURL outResultingURL: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURL?>) throws`

  moves the item to the trash folder returning the item’s location in the trash via the inout pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The removeItemAtPath method deletes them. They're gone. If you want to move something to the trash, you need to use [NSWorkSpace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html). You can see an example of moving an entire directory to the trash here: [Move directory to trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665660/move-directory-to-trash)

Answer (score 1):

basically unixy systems manage files the same way, there is a ref count, that is the number of hard links + times the file is open... So you can rm an open file, and the file will still exist, you can write to it, and read from it, with a valid `file descriptor` or `FILE *` stream object, then when it is closed the file will actually be removed from the disk...

```
int fd = open("somefile", O_RDWR);
unlink("somefile"); // removes somefile from the directory listing, but not disk
write(fd, "hello", 5);
lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET); // seek to start of file 
char buffer[6] = {0};
read(fd,buffer,5); // reads in "hello"
close(fd); // last reference removed, file is removed.
```

if you want to move a file to the Trash, that is a different operation and specific to OS X and iOS